# Rails - model association for recursive user model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

In my user model, I have

```
  belongs_to :admin_creator, foreign_key: :created_by_user_id, class_name: "User"
```

and in my create controller action I have...

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_create_params)
    @user.created_by_user_id = current_user.id
    @user.status_code = 'P' #set status code to pending

    begin
      @user.save!
      render json: "User #{@user.email} added", status: :created 
    rescue StandardError => e
      render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity 
    end

  end
```

How can I recast my code to to use model association for "current_user" who would be the admin_creator?

When create action is called, current_user is the current admin user who is adding another (child) user account. I'm thinking it would be along the lines of... @user = current_user.users.build(user_create_params) or similar

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: Updated my question. See last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `has_many` to the `User` model like this:

```
has_many :admin_children, foreign_key: :created_by_user_id, class_name: "User"
```

Then you can do:

```
current_user.admin_children.create(user_create_params)
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick!! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Not really related but same source as above - in this post, I asked a question regarding best practice when saving model data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042063/rails-which-is-a-better-approach-to-saving-model-updates